# sending an input type value to a button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a value from an input text to a button, is it possible to do that?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="test_name"  class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
    <span class="input-group-btn">  
        <button class="comments btn btn-primary btn-sm" test="{{test_name}}" data-catid="{{likes.id}}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment">Comment</span> 
        </button>
     </span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve a little more. What do you mean by `send the value to the button`? Under what event are you trying to do this?

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is when a user press the button the "test" id should containt their inputted text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve, is it something like this??

```
$(document).on('click','button.comments', function(){
    var input_val = $('input.chat-input').val();
    $(this).find('span').attr('test',input_val).text(input_val);
});
```

You can see the inspect element on chrome for attribute test change it value like textbox value or not..

Comment: thank you , actually i got how to proceed with the answer using your idea

Comment: Welcome. Your question is not quite clear enough for SO. If you can give more explanation, then we could. Anyway, good luck!!